# Is there a (free) reliable place to get statistics from sites, more reliable than Alexa, Quantcast, Compete?

Tags: traffic, statistics, alexa, quantcast

I mean, seems there's no way. I am just asking in case someone knows of a recent new site being more accurate. I am aware of Alexa's, Compete and Quantcast inaccuracies and/or limited system/range of sites to get their stats.

I also know about websitegrader perhaps being a little more accurate (although not sure if that's the data I am after). And read Seomoz tools are reliable. I am yet though looking for a free solution, a 'reliable' Alexa. And not a place depending on a toolbar installation, an easy to trick place, or one with stats way too off, or of a very limited range of sites.  I am almost sure there's nothing new, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: You know almost all the alternatives. I may also add http://www.similarweb.com/ and http://www.rank2traffic.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. No one that has that kind of data because it relies on tracking software being installed on every website which is obviously not happening. Sites like Google Analytics and other trackers that have a large client base don't release most of this data they have for free or at all. Alexa and similar sites are the best you can do (and they just aren't very good).

Comment: +1 for "Alexa and similar sites are the best you can do (***and they just aren't very good***)".